# How to extract from a large dataset hourly daily means by level from a factor variable and estimate other statistics

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, lubridate

The dataframe `df1` summarizes different datetimes in which people has gone to a public toilet for a specific period of time (let's say between "2017-06-01" and "2017-06-30"). The column `Zone` specifies the area where the toilet was placed, being a factor with two levels: `A` (a party area) or`B` (a residence area).

I show below a reproducible example of what I have. This example contains only two days to reduce the size of the example dataset. In order to create `df1` I had first to create 4 separate dataframes and then bind them to create the dataframe `df1` (I had error when a tried to create `df1` at once). `df1` has 193 rows.

```
options(digits.secs=3)
day_1_A<- data.frame(Datetime= ymd_hms(c("2017-06-01 00:04:17.986","2017-06-01 00:17:43.456","2017-06-01 00:22:43.456","2017-06-01 00:34:43.456","2017-06-01 00:45:43.456","2017-06-01 01:15:23.275","2017-06-01 01:41:32.609","2017-06-01 02:04:17.986","2017-06-01 02:17:43.456","2017-06-01 03:15:23.275","2017-06-01 03:41:32.609","2017-06-01 04:04:17.986","2017-06-01 04:17:43.456","2017-06-01 05:15:23.275","2017-06-01 05:41:32.609","2017-06-01 06:04:17.986","2017-06-01 06:17:43.456","2017-06-01 07:15:23.275","2017-06-01 07:41:32.609","2017-06-01 08:04:17.986","2017-06-01 08:17:43.456","2017-06-01 09:15:23.275","2017-06-01 09:41:32.609","2017-06-01 10:04:17.986","2017-06-01 10:17:43.456","2017-06-01 11:15:23.275","2017-06-01 11:41:32.609","2017-06-01 12:04:17.986","2017-06-01 12:17:43.456","2017-06-01 13:15:23.275","2017-06-01 13:41:32.609","2017-06-01 14:04:17.986","2017-06-01 14:17:43.456","2017-06-01 15:17:23.275","2017-06-01 15:41:32.609","2017-06-01 16:04:17.986","2017-06-01 16:17:43.456","2017-06-01 17:15:23.275","2017-06-01 17:41:32.609","2017-06-01 18:04:17.986","2017-06-01 18:17:43.456","2017-06-01 19:15:23.275","2017-06-01 19:41:32.609","2017-06-01 20:04:17.986","2017-06-01 20:17:43.456","2017-06-01 21:15:23.275","2017-06-01 21:41:32.609","2017-06-01 22:04:17.986","2017-06-01 22:17:43.456","2017-06-01 23:15:23.275","2017-06-01 23:41:32.609")),
                 ToiletZone = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"))

day_1_B<- data.frame(Datetime= ymd_hms(c("2017-06-01 00:04:17.986","2017-06-01 00:17:43.456","2017-06-01 01:15:23.275","2017-06-01 01:41:32.609","2017-06-01 02:04:17.986","2017-06-01 02:17:43.456","2017-06-01 03:15:23.275","2017-06-01 03:41:32.609","2017-06-01 04:04:17.986","2017-06-01 04:17:43.456","2017-06-01 05:15:23.275","2017-06-01 05:41:32.609","2017-06-01 06:04:17.986","2017-06-01 06:17:43.456","2017-06-01 07:15:23.275","2017-06-01 07:41:32.609","2017-06-01 08:04:17.986","2017-06-01 08:17:43.456","2017-06-01 09:15:23.275","2017-06-01 09:41:32.609","2017-06-01 10:04:17.986","2017-06-01 10:17:43.456","2017-06-01 11:15:23.275","2017-06-01 11:41:32.609","2017-06-01 12:04:17.986","2017-06-01 12:17:43.456","2017-06-01 13:15:23.275","2017-06-01 13:41:32.609","2017-06-01 14:04:17.986","2017-06-01 14:17:43.456","2017-06-01 15:15:23.275","2017-06-01 15:41:32.609","2017-06-01 16:04:17.986","2017-06-01 16:17:43.456","2017-06-01 17:15:23.275","2017-06-01 17:41:32.609","2017-06-01 18:04:17.986","2017-06-01 18:17:43.456","2017-06-01 19:15:23.275","2017-06-01 19:41:32.609","2017-06-01 20:04:17.986","2017-06-01 20:17:43.456","2017-06-01 21:15:23.275","2017-06-01 21:41:32.609","2017-06-01 22:04:17.986","2017-06-01 22:17:43.456","2017-06-01 23:15:23.275","2017-06-01 23:41:32.609")),
                 ToiletZone = c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"))

day_2_A<- data.frame(Datetime= ymd_hms(c("2017-06-02 00:17:43.456","2017-06-02 00:48:43.456","2017-06-02 01:15:23.275","2017-06-02 01:52:23.275","2017-06-02 02:04:17.986","2017-06-02 02:17:43.456","2017-06-02 03:15:23.275","2017-06-02 03:41:32.609","2017-06-02 04:04:17.986","2017-06-02 04:17:43.456","2017-06-02 05:15:23.275","2017-06-02 05:41:32.609","2017-06-02 06:04:17.986","2017-06-02 06:17:43.456","2017-06-02 07:15:23.275","2017-06-02 07:41:32.609","2017-06-02 08:04:17.986","2017-06-02 08:17:43.456","2017-06-02 09:15:23.275","2017-06-02 09:41:32.609","2017-06-02 10:04:17.986","2017-06-02 10:17:43.456","2017-06-02 11:15:23.275","2017-06-02 11:41:32.609","2017-06-02 12:04:17.986","2017-06-02 12:17:43.456","2017-06-02 13:15:23.275","2017-06-02 13:41:32.609","2017-06-02 14:04:17.986","2017-06-02 14:17:43.456","2017-06-02 15:15:23.275","2017-06-02 15:41:32.609","2017-06-02 16:04:17.986","2017-06-02 16:17:43.456","2017-06-02 17:15:23.275","2017-06-02 17:41:32.609","2017-06-02 18:04:17.986","2017-06-02 18:17:43.456","2017-06-02 19:15:23.275","2017-06-02 19:41:32.609","2017-06-02 20:04:17.986","2017-06-02 20:17:43.456","2017-06-02 21:15:23.275","2017-06-02 21:41:32.609","2017-06-02 22:04:17.986","2017-06-02 22:17:43.456","2017-06-02 23:15:23.275","2017-06-02 23:41:32.609")),
                 ToiletZone = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"))

day_2_B<- data.frame(Datetime= ymd_hms(c("2017-06-02 00:04:17.986","2017-06-02 01:15:23.275","2017-06-02 02:04:17.986","2017-06-02 02:17:43.456","2017-06-02 03:15:23.275","2017-06-02 03:41:32.609","2017-06-02 04:04:17.986","2017-06-02 04:17:43.456","2017-06-02 05:15:23.275","2017-06-02 05:41:32.609","2017-06-02 06:04:17.986","2017-06-02 06:17:43.456","2017-06-02 07:15:23.275","2017-06-02 07:41:32.609","2017-06-02 08:04:17.986","2017-06-02 08:17:43.456","2017-06-02 09:15:23.275","2017-06-02 09:41:32.609","2017-06-02 10:04:17.986","2017-06-02 10:17:43.456","2017-06-02 11:15:23.275","2017-06-02 11:41:32.609","2017-06-02 12:04:17.986","2017-06-02 12:17:43.456","2017-06-02 13:15:23.275","2017-06-02 13:41:32.609","2017-06-02 14:04:17.986","2017-06-02 14:17:43.456","2017-06-02 15:15:23.275","2017-06-02 15:41:32.609","2017-06-02 16:04:17.986","2017-06-02 16:17:43.456","2017-06-02 17:15:23.275","2017-06-02 17:41:32.609","2017-06-02 18:04:17.986","2017-06-02 18:17:43.456","2017-06-02 19:15:23.275","2017-06-02 19:41:32.609","2017-06-02 20:04:17.986","2017-06-02 20:17:43.456","2017-06-02 21:15:23.275","2017-06-02 21:41:32.609","2017-06-02 22:04:17.986","2017-06-02 22:17:43.456","2017-06-02 23:15:23.275","2017-06-02 23:41:32.609")),
                 ToiletZone = c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"))


df1<- rbind(day_1_A,day_1_B,day_2_A,day_2_B)
df1

> df1
                   Datetime ToiletZone
1   2017-06-01 00:04:17.986          A
2   2017-06-01 00:17:43.455          A
3   2017-06-01 00:22:43.455          A
4   2017-06-01 00:34:43.455          A
5   2017-06-01 00:45:43.455          A
6   2017-06-01 01:15:23.275          A
.               .                    .
.               .                    .
.               .                    .
193 2017-06-02 23:41:32.608          B
```

For some reasons I won't explain here, I need to calculate for EACH DAY and for EACH ZONE a statistic called `θ`, that could be defined as the coefficient of the division of the "average hourly number of visits to the toilet during the day" (`Hourly_daily_μ`) by the "average hourly number of visits for the entire period of interest" (`Overall_hourly_μ`).

I show in a picture what I would expect from the previous example (the columns `Hourly_daily_μ_A`, `Hourly_daily_μ_B`, `Overall_hourly_μ_A` and `Overall_hourly_μ_A` are incorporated to clarify the calculations. The columns that I really need are  `θ_A` and `θ_B`):
[image]

Why `Hourly_daily_μ_A` is 51/24 on 2017-06-01? Because this day there were 51 persons that went to the toilet. Hence, if we divide between 24 we get the hourly mean of people that went to the toilet this day.

Why `Overall_hourly_μ_A` is the same for each zone for the different days? Because it is an overall mean for each zone. Here we want to know what is the general average of people that go to the toilet per hour. In this example, we know that 99 persons went to the toilet between the 1st June and the 2nd June in the Zone A. So we divide this between the total number of hours (48 hours in the example) and we get the overall hourly mean of people that go to the toilet in the zone A. It is a unique value for each Zone.

Why `θ_A` is (51*48)/(24*99) on the 2017-06-01? Because is the result of dividing `Hourly_daily_μ_A` (51/24) by `Overall_hourly_μ_A` (99/48).

Does anyone know how to do it? My dataframe is quite large so I guess that the package `data.table` could be a good option.

Comment: Sorry, I get some different numbers -

Comment: If I'm not wrong, in the example there are 51 people that go to the toilet in the Zone A and 48 in the Zone B on the 1st June. On the 2nd June, there are 48 people that go to the toilet in the Zone A and 46 that go to the toilet B. If you sum all, it is 193 people (the number of rows of the example dataset).

Comment: I tried couple of ways, `df1 %>% group_by(ToiletZone) %>% summarise(n = n())` gives 99 and 94 as yours.  Next I converted the 'Datetime' to hourly with `ceiling` and checked the frequency

Comment: The calculations are "easy", but I don't know how to do it. I want to get for each day and zone a statistic that is the result of dividing the hourly average number of people that goes to the toilet this day (`Hourly_daily_μ`) by the overall hourly average number of people that go to the toilet using all the days from the dataset (`Overall_hourly_μ`).

Comment: May be I missed the year part `df1 %>% group_by(ToiletZone, date = as.Date(Datetime)) %>% summarise(v1 = n_distinct(ceiling_date(Datetime, 'hour')))`

Comment: `table(df1$ToiletZone, as.Date(df1$Datetime))`. I think you want to take the combined year 39 + 12 = 51

Comment: I added a picture that hopefully helps to the understanding of the issue...

Comment: I am interested in the parameters `θ_A` and `θ_B`

Comment: @ akrun, I found a mistake about the years... In some rows I had the year "2016" instead of the year "2017". I've solved this... Maybe that's why you found different results...

Comment: That could be the reason

Comment: The last part is it multiplication `df1 %>% group_by(ToiletZone) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% group_by(dayMonth = format(as.Date(Datetime), "2017-%m-%d"), add = TRUE) %>% summarise(Dailyhourly = n()/24, Overallhourly = first(n)/n())`

Comment: Now, with the new data, the `n = 147` instead of 99

Comment: You can check the updated solution in my post

Comment: 144? Now, when I do `table(df1$ToiletZone, as.Date(df1$Datetime))` I get the table I show in the picture, so I guess now my dataset is ok.

Comment: Ok, it is a confusion.  Can you check the output below

Comment: I've updated the picture I was showing since I didn't add coefficients of the division. Now I show the coefficients and what I see is different from what you show... Alexis in other answer shows what I would hope to find... Do you know the reason?

Comment: I get the same than him @akrun... Try now. Alexis warned me that I had a type error in the line `df1<- rbind(day_1_A,day_1_B,day_2_A,day_2_B)`. Instead of this I had `df1<- rbind(day_1_A,day_1_B,day_2_A,day_2_A)`. Could be this the problem? I've been able to reproduced his scripts satisfactorily.

Comment: I get `unique(ans[, .(ToiletZone, Theta)])
   ToiletZone     Theta
1:          A 2.4242424
2:          A 0.9696970
3:          B 1.0212766
4:          B 0.5106383`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to floor your dates to a day unit and then you can use it for grouping.
With `data.table`:

```
setDT(df1)

df1[, Date := floor_date(Datetime, "day")]

daily <- df1[, .(DailyCount = .N, DailyAvg = .N / 24), by = .(ToiletZone, Date)]
overall <- daily[, .(Total = sum(DailyCount) / (.N * 24)), by = .(ToiletZone)]

overall[daily, .(ToiletZone, Date, Theta = DailyAvg / Total), on = "ToiletZone"]
   ToiletZone       Date     Theta
1:          A 2017-06-01 1.0303030
2:          B 2017-06-01 1.0212766
3:          A 2017-06-02 0.9696970
4:          B 2017-06-02 0.9787234
```

And hourly would be similar,
just change `floor_date` and adjust some denominators:

```
df1[, Date := floor_date(Datetime, "hour")]

hourly <- df1[, .(HourlyCount = .N), by = .(ToiletZone, Date)]
overall <- hourly[, .(Total = sum(HourlyCount) / .N), by = "ToiletZone"]

ans <- overall[hourly, .(ToiletZone, Date, Theta = HourlyCount / Total), on = "ToiletZone"]
```

BTW, the last lines are a join,
you can think of them as a left join with, respectively,
`daily` and `hourly` as the left-hand table.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. One doubt, can I use the same script if I increase the period with data? I will desire the same: a 'zheta' per zone and per day which divide the hourly mean of people that go to the toilet in this day in this zone (numerator) between the 'Overall hourly mean of people' that go to the toilet in this zone for the whole period. I guess I can change the number of row and it still work, but just in case I ask you...

Comment: @Dekike yes, I think it should work, it makes no assumptions regarding the amount of days in your data.

Comment: Hi @Alexis, I am sorry for disturbing you again. How could I do if I want to calculate a "Theta" by hour instead than by day? That is, on each hour I divide the number of visits in this hour to the toilet by the overall hourly mean of visits to the toilet for the whole period. I think I might use this instead of a "Theta" by day...

Comment: @Dekike I've updated the answer, doesn't fit in a comment. BTW, the code in your question has a typo, you used `day_2_A` two times.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be do group by frequency count, do some calculations to get the expected output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = floor_date(Datetime, "hour")) %>% 
  group_by(ToiletZone, Date) %>% 
  mutate(hourlyCount = n(), HourlyAvg = hourlyCount/24) %>% 
  group_by(ToiletZone) %>% 
  mutate(Total = sum(hourlyCount)/ n() * 24) %>% 
  group_by(Date = as.Date(Date), add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(Theta = hourlyCount[1]/Total[1]) %>%
  spread(ToiletZone, Theta)
```

Comment: Hi akrun, I added an example to try both clarify what I need and to know if your code does what I need...

Comment: I need to calculate for each zone and day the average hourly number of people that go to the toilet. On the other hand, I calculate the average hourly number of people that go to the toilet BUT FOR THE WHOLE PERIOD (in this case the days 2017-06-01 and 2017-06-02). And finally, I get the statistic that I need that is the division between the first and the second parameter.

Comment: @Dekike I got 99 part, but what is the 48

Comment: The number of hours. For the daily mean you divide by 24 (1 day = 24 hours), but for the "overall mean", you have to divide by the total number of hours of the period, in this case since the period are two days, 48 hours. 99 is the amount of people that go to the toilet in two days, and dividing it by 48 hours you get the hourly mean for the whole period.

Comment: @Dekike  I usedd `ceiling_date` earlier, but ddue to the confusion in the days, have to change it.